# Check if Package Installation will Result in Dependency Conflicts in Python

Tags: python, pip

Before installing a package in my Python environment using `pip install <some-package>==<version>`, is it possible for me to check if doing so will cause a dependency conflict, given what has been installed in the environment already?

I am looking for a script I can run before each install. Ideally, it should be able to evaluate any potential conflicts that will be caused by the specific version of the package that I am trying to install.

Comment: you could freeze the current env to a req file, then add the new package and install the req file. pip resolves all packages in the req file together before installing anything and will fail if there are any conflicts

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `--dry-run`, so

```
pip install --dry-run <whatever>
```

From [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-dry-run)

> `--dry-run`
>
> Don’t actually install anything, just print what would be. Can be used in combination with --ignore-installed to ‘resolve’ the requirements.